# Install specific package version in Microsoft R Open

Tags: r, package, microsoft-r

How do I install a specific package version in Microsoft R Open (MRO)?  I am familiar with the `checkpoint("YYYY-MM-DD")` function for changing ALL package versions to a specific MRO snapshot.  I do not want to do this.  I only want to change the version of a single package.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To install a specific version of a package, download the package from the CRAN or MRAN archive (src/contrib/Archive) and install it with

```
install.packages("/path/to/pkg/src", type="source")
```

where/path/to/pkg/src is the path to the downloaded package.

To get the package directly from a specific MRAN snapshot, use

```
install.packages('pkg', repos='https://mran.microsoft.com/snapshot/YYYY-MM-DD/')
```

To also get the dependencies, you want

```
install.packages('pkg', repos='https://mran.microsoft.com/snapshot/YYYY-MM-DD/', dependencies=TRUE)
```

Be aware, however, that the version you choose may not be compatible with the version of MRO you are using. This is why MRO uses a specific MRAN snapshot--to ensure compatibility of available packages with the specific MRO.

Comment: I was trying this but it does not get dependencies.

Comment: @StevenC.Howell, does adding `dependencies = TRUE` install them?

Comment: @StvenC.Howell,  as @wibeasley says, set `dependencies=TRUE`, something like so:  `install.packages("package_name", repos="url_to_the_repo_you_need", dependencies=TRUE)`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too familiar with the `checkpoint()` function but what I do see is that you can set project to a directory of packages you want to project be installed from the `MRAN` snapshot for the date specified for `snapshotDate`. It defaults to current working directory using `getwd()`, so I would assume if you changed the directory and had a specific package there, you would be able to workaround that way.